# Convex Optimization, Non-negativity constraints, Interior-Point or Projected Gradient?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

Assume I have the following convex optimization problem, with a convex objective function on conventional non-negativity constraints.

\begin{align} 
    \min_{x \geq 0}  \sum_{i=1}^{I} a_{i}x_{i}  - f(\bf{x}),
\end{align}

where $\bf{x}$ is a vector of dimension I, $f(\bf{x})$ is a concave function, and the dimension of $I$ is very large. The solution is sparse, meaning that in the optimal vector there is a large amount of zeros. This comes from the fact that for some entries $i$

\begin{align}
a_{i} > f_{i}(\bf{x}^{*})
\end{align}

where $f_{i}(\bf{x})$ corresponds to $\partial f(\bf{x}^{*})/x_{i}$. Since the function is convex, I know that the KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient for global optimality, all local optima are also global, and the set of solutions is convex.

However, I have questions about how to solve for the optimum numerically,

1. If I use a Projected Gradient Method, I have seen on the internet that the projection step of the algorithm is just

$$ x^{k+1} = \max\left\{0,x^{k}-\alpha_{k}(a-\nabla f(x^{k}))\right\} $$

However, I have not found a proof or a paper that shows this. Can someone provide a proof or reference?

2. The other option is to use Interior-Point methods. However, what confuses me in this case is that when one uses barrier methods, how does it work if the solution is not interior, but in the boundary for some entries?

Comment: You meant to write $x^{k+1} = \max(0,x^k-\alpha_k (a - \nabla f(x^k))$, right ? What is $f_i$ ? Finally, do you know that the othorgonal projection $P_C(x)$ of a point $x \in \mathbb R^I$ onto the negative orthant $C=\mathbb R_+^I$ is given by $P_C(x) = (\max(0,x_1),\ldots,\max(0,x_I))$ ?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post in line to clarify the language.  That comment about the orthogonal projection is what I do not know.

Comment: Ok, first note that $C = C_1 \times \ldots \times C_I$, where $C_i = \mathbb R_+$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,I\}$. Let $p = (p_1,\ldots,p_I) := P_C(x)$. Do you see why $p_i = P_{C_i}(x_i)$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,I\}$ ? Next, do you see why $P_{C_i}(x_i) = \arg\min_{z_i \in \mathbb R_+}(z_i-x_i)^2 = \max(0,x_i)$ ?

Comment: @dohmatob , thanks that is totally clear. Do you mind providing a little bit of intuitions of why the problem is not combinatorial, i.e why I do not have to find a solution for any combination of 0s? Is this because of the convexity and the gradients?

Comment: I've posted a response below. Let me know which part of it you don't understand. Also note that you'll have to do some personal digging to really learning these things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer.** *This would be a very long comment. Posting here in hopes that the OP finds it helpful. Please google the references I mention rather colloquially below.*

---

Let $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable convex function  and let $G:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ be an extended-value proper convex function. Consider the minimization of the sum $H:=F+G$. By first-order optimality conditions, a point $x_\star \in \mathbb R^n$ is a minimizer of $H$ iff $0 \in \partial H(x_\star)$, the *subdifferential* of $H$ at $x_\star$. Now, under mild conditions, the subdifferential of $H$ is the sum of subdifferentials of $F$ and $G$ pointwise. We deduce that
$$
0 \in \nabla F(x_\star) + \partial G(x_\star),\text{ i.e }-\nabla F(x_\star) \in \partial G(x_\star).
\tag{1}
$$

Things like (1) are referred to as *variational inequalities / inclusions* (a terminology likely due to R.T. Rockafellar).

Continuing our intuitionist *démarche*, observe that, for positive $\alpha$, (1) can be written as $x_\star - \alpha \nabla F(x_\star) \in x_\star + \alpha \partial G(x_\star) = (I + \alpha\partial G)(x_\star)$. Now, because $\partial G$ is a *maximal monotone operator* (due to a result of Rockafellar from the 70s), we can invert the last variational inclusion to get

$$
x_\star = (I+\alpha \partial G)^{-1}(x_\star-\alpha \nabla F(x_\star)) = \mbox{prox}_{\alpha G}(x_\star-\alpha F(x_\star)),
$$

where $\mbox{prox}_{\alpha G}:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is the proximal operator of $G$ at level $\alpha$, defined by

$$
\mbox{prox}_{\alpha G}(x) := (I + \alpha\partial G)^{-1} (x) = \arg\min_{z \in \mathbb R^n} (1/2) \|z-x\|_2^2 + \alpha G(z).
$$
Thus,

> *The minimizers of $x_\star$ of $H$ and the fixed-points of the operator $x \mapsto \mbox{prox}_{\alpha G}(x-\alpha\nabla F(x))$ coincide. The proximal / projected gradient algorithms can then be seen as being nothing but algorithmic ways for computing such fixed points!*

Now, Lions and co-workers have shown that if $F$ is, say, with Lipschitz-continuous gradient, then for appropriate stepsizes $(\alpha_k)_k$, (1) can be solved by iterating the following scheme:

- $x^{k+1} \leftarrow \mbox{prox}_{\alpha_k G}(x^k - \alpha_k \nabla F(x_k))$
- $k \leftarrow k + 1$,

Finally, in case $G$ is the indicator function of a closed convex subset $C$ of $\mathbb R^n$ (meaning that $G$ evalutes to $0$ on $C$, and $\infty$ outside of $C$), then $\mbox{prox}_{G} = \mbox{proj}_C$.

Comment: @j.kookalinski I dunno, I have also seen this referred to as a "variational inequality" even for this generic setting

Comment: @Zim do you have a reference? it's pretty clear on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_inequality and some of Rockafellar's works I've read

Comment: @j.kookalinski Concerning your very first remark, yes, subgradient (i.e an element of the subdifferential) at a point is the normal cone at that point. The proximal operator is the inverse of identity mapping + subddifferential, then evaluate that at the point in question. This gives the orthogonal projection.

Comment: (Comment continued) Concerning your other comments, what I'm maximizing here is simplicity, to help the OP with their specific question, without making things unnecessarily complicated. All of these, while using only rudimentary concepts. For the bigger picture on the subject, the interested reader should refer to Rockafellar's standard text, and more recently the book by Combettes and Bauschke.

Comment: @j.kookalinski e.g., it is in the book by Bauschke/Combettes, vol. 2